# App Transport Security

Tags: ios, swift

I know this question has been asked before but I have tried all the proposed solutions. My info.plist file looks like this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>BNDL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>
        </dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>parse.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

This error happens right after I pick an image on my application the code is in timelinetable view controller here.

```
 func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
        let pickedImage: UIImage = (info as NSDictionary).objectForKey(UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage) as! UIImage
        //Scale
        let scaledImage = self.scaleImageWith(pickedImage, and:CGSizeMake(80, 80))

        let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(scaledImage)
        let imageFile:PFFile = PFFile(name: "Profile", data: imageData )

        let user = PFUser.currentUser()
        user.setObject(imageFile, forKey: "profilePicture")
        user.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil  {

                print("saving")
            }
        }

        picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

I am using parse as my backend.

Comment: Why is the `NSAppTransportSecurity` key in the plist twice and nested?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSAppTransportSecurity` is nested in your .plist file that's why you are getting this issue. I fixed your plist and it is stated below. Hope it will work for you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>BNDL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: @TanmayBhanushali: I edited my answer. Hope now it will work for you.

Comment: Sorry the same error keeps showing up. If I archive the application and export it to the app store will it work on iPhones?